# how to use payment gateway in iOS app without getting rejected by apple?

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am facing a problem while attaching the payment gateway. I don't want to use the in app purchase but apple don't allow any other gateway.

so any help? anybody?

Comment: paypal is another options .. n app is not rejected

Comment: And I want root access to the iPhone...what do you want us to do?  The rules are the rules.

Comment: payu and paypal gets rejected because apple does not allow the use of third party payment gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download leatest Sdk from here https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK

Comment: payu and paypal gets rejected because apple does not allow the use of third party payment gateway

Comment: can you name one such app or send me the link of any such app?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use authorize .net payment gateway which is secure and easy.

Comment: payu and paypal gets rejected because apple does not allow the use of third party payment gateway

Comment: I already implemented paypal in two application, but app not rejected because of this reason. Post the apple comment so that we can know what exactly he is saying.